# What tools do you know for storage, version control and deploy as API service of ML models?

Tags: machine-learning, data-science

I found https://dataversioncontrol.com and https://hydrosphere.io/ml-lambda/. What can be more?

Answer (score 0):

Convert your ML pipeline to a standardized text-based representation, and use regular version control tools (such as Git). For example, the [PMML standard](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-3/GeneralStructure.html) can represent most popular R, Scikit-Learn and Apache Spark ML transformation and model types. Better yet, after conversion to the standardized representation, all these models become directly comparable with one another (eg. measuring the "complexity" of random forest model objects between different ML frameworks).

You can build whatever APIs you like on top of this versioned base layer.

To get started with the PMML standard, please check out the [Java PMML API](https://github.com/jpmml) backend project, and its [Openscoring REST API](https://github.com/openscoring) frontend project.